# Can an Android library project have its own SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing a library that will be able to be used across multiple apps. It serves the exact same function in each, and one of the goals of the library is to be as easy and painless to use as possible. In that way, I was hoping to use a SQLite db to store some important information relevant to the library, but NOT to the host app. I searched around and couldn't find anything confirming or denying the ability for libraries to have their own databases. Does anyone know if it is possible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, that depends upon what you mean by "the ability for libraries to have their own databases".

There is nothing stopping an Android library project -- or even a plain Android-compiled JAR -- from using `SQLiteDatabase`, `SQLiteOpenHelper`, and kin. So, from a *code* standpoint, the library can have its own database. You will need a `Context` object from the host app, at least for use with `SQLiteOpenHelper`, though.

That is because, from a *file* standpoint, the library does not exist outside of its hosting app. Hence, the database *file* will be stored in the app's portion of internal storage by default. You will need to take some steps to try to minimize the odds of collisions on database file name (e.g., mangle your library's package name into the filename), so the host app does not attempt to accidentally work with your library's data. The `Context` is supplied to `SQLiteOpenHelper` mostly so that it can call methods like `getDatabasePath()` to figure out where to put the database file.

Also, bear in mind that the host app can access your database, just as it can access its own. Please make sure that you document the rules regarding this database (e.g., do not use it directly, but use the library's API instead).

Comment: How about if you want one database per device (not per app)?  Store it on shared storage. But then you would probably need to take more care regarding database upgrades and different library project versions on the same device. I'm not sure about issues regarding concurrency.

Comment: @MarkCarter: "How about if you want one database per device (not per app)?" -- there's no great solution for that. "Store it on shared storage" -- the only "shared storage" that would qualify would be somewhere on external storage that is not tied to a specific app, otherwise the database would be deleted when that app is uninstalled, regardless of the existence of any other app. "take more care regarding database upgrades and different library project versions" -- that's what makes this not great.

Comment: @MarkCarter: "I'm not sure about issues regarding concurrency" -- that's the part I'm least worried about. SQLite itself already uses locking patterns to handle cross-process access. While that particular feature is not utilized much, if any, on Android, it is used a fair bit in other environments (e.g., SQLite is the default database for Rails apps, last I checked).

Comment: @CommonsWare An alternative would be to distribute a 'library' APK via Google Play (other app stores also available). Data sharing using a content provider. At least then it would have its own protected space to store the underlying SQLite db. But then you have the nastiness of an app depending on another app. And then, once again, version control could be messy. Hmmm...